# Problem sharing laptop Internet connection

Tags: internet, sharing, ethernet

I have tried to share my laptop Internet conection to a PC by configuring the Eth0 connection of my laptop with "Share with others" selected. The Eth0 connection of the PC is DHCP Automatic. It keeps connecting and disconnecting every 2 or 3 seconds. Am I doing something wrong?

Both computers are running Ubuntu.

Comment: If your question has been solved, could you please mark it as such by posting your solution below and accepting it, rather than by making an edit? Thanks!

Comment: *Googling* around found this issue is caused by a bug. The bug was fixed supposedly downloaded and installed in my system with update manager but I was having the issue even when Ubuntu 11.10 is up to date. So, I went to connection manager/etho config/IPV6 an set it up to IGNORE. Restart my laptop and problem solved.

Comment: How do I mark it as *solved*? @WarriorIng64

Comment: @BrunoPablo You need to take your from the comment and post it as an actual answer below. Then in a little while you can mark your own answer as correct.

Comment: @Bruno That is actually a comment, not an answer. What I meant was going down to the box below marked "Your Answer", entering it there, and clicking the "Post Your Answer" button. After the answer is posted, click the checkmark icon to the left of it to mark it as accepted. If you have additional questions, please see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq).

Comment: @root45 Ah, you just beat me to it!

Comment: Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead. (Not enough priv.)

Comment: @BrunoPablo *(facepalms)* Sorry, I forgot about that restriction! Curiously, it's not listed under the list of privileges...maybe I should ask about that on Meta. There is currently a [discussion](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1819/making-users-wait-to-answer-their-questions-hindering-a-new-users-progress) about your issue there. In the meantime, could you please wait a little bit and try again after those 7 hours are up? Thanks!

Comment: No problem @WarriorIng64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Googling* around found this issue is caused by a bug. The bug was fixed supposedly donwloaded and installed in my sistem with upda  the having the issue even when Ubuntu 11.10 is up to date. So, I went to connection manager/etho config/IPV6 an set it up to IGNORE. Restart my laptop and problem solved.